# How can I view iTunes U videos via Home Sharing on iPad with iOS 6?

Tags: home-sharing, itunes-u

Before upgrading to iOS 6, I can just watch iTunes U videos with all other videos from my Mac's iTunes library in the Videos app on my iPad via Home Sharing. However, the first time I open the Videos app on iOS 6, I was told I should watch iTunes U contents in the iTunes U app. But I see no videos in the iTunes U app.

Answer (score 3):

I could resolve the issue by removing the Podcasts and iTunes U apps from the iPad. Afterwards the shared items are visible in the Videos app.

Comment: I only had to remove the iTunes U app. It seems Apple forgot to build Home Sharing into Podcasts and iTunes U. Aside: This is the first thing I haven't liked about those apps.